# DOCX4J How to add cell and bind variable in a table

Tags: java, xml, docx4j

I'm using DOCX4J and I have docx with template for table, that template contains variable that will be replaced.

[image: Table]

There can be several type and in each type many reference.
The type never has any quantity.

So first I want to add more cells and columns dynamically and after bind the variable with the good values (values are store in a TreeModel (DefaultTreeModel)). There is a way to do this ? Probably manipulate the XML of my docx ?
Obivously I want to preserve the style of the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest to use OpenDoPE: wrap a repeat content control around "type" and another around "reference".   Or you can write code yourself which uses the docx4j API to clone your table rows, then do your variable insertion.